# MySqlReader in the wrong place?

Tags: c#, mysql

I have this section of code that checks the user information already in the database, then updates the information if the data is the same:

```
// Connection to the database.
DbConnect();

// If the Connection is sound, checks the Username and Password are the same as the input.
try
{
    mySqlCommand = mySqlConnect.CreateCommand();
    mySqlCommand.CommandText = Database_MySQLDef.SELECTFROMUSERS + "UserName = '" + UModel.Name + "' AND UserPassword = '" + UModel.Pwd + "';";
    mySqlReader = mySqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

    while (mySqlReader.Read())
    {
        // If the query could not be found, outputs an error.
        if (UModel.Pwd != Convert.ToString(mySqlReader["UserPassword"]))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Query does not match");
        }
        // If the query is found, changes the input of the password.
        else
        {
            try
            {
                // Updates the UserPassword in the Db.
                mySqlCommand = mySqlConnect.CreateCommand();
                mySqlCommand.CommandText = Database_MySQLDef.UPDATEUSERS + "UserPassword = '" + UModel.ConfirmPwd + "' WHERE UserName = '" + UModel.Name + "';";
                mySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (MySqlException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            // Closes the Reader and empties the Command object.
            mySqlReader.Close();
            mySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
catch (MySqlException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
// When the query is finished, terminates the connection to the Database.
finally
{
    if (mySqlConnect != null)
    {
        mySqlConnect.Close();
    }
}
```

**NOTE** I wrote this a few months ago when I was just starting out, so I know it's ugly. However the main issue at the moment is that the position of the `MySqlReader.Close()` seems to be in the wrong place. Where it is now (after the `try/catch` block in the `else` statement)

```
catch (MySqlException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
// Closes the Reader and empties the Command object.
mySqlReader.Close();
mySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

it returns an error:

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.

Whereas I originally had it *before* the `try/catch` block in the `else` statement

```
else
{
    try
    {
        // Closes the Reader and empties the Command object.
        mySqlReader.Close();
        mySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

which gave the error:

> Invalid attempt to Read when reader is closed.

Can someone point out what is going wrong and what I can do to fix it?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=Invalid+attempt+to+Read+when+reader+is+closed.&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb&gfe_rd=ctrl&ei=EIQyU6mdBKbe8gfOqoGQBg&gws_rd=cr

Comment: put `SqlReader.Close()` in `finally` block instead of putting it in `Try` block

Comment: or put `SqlReader.Close()` after you close your `while` loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should break from `while` loop instead of `else`. And after the cycle you should close the reader and re-create the `mySqlCommand`. Something like this:

```
{
    bool passwordFounded = false;
    while (mySqlReader.Read())
    {
        if (UModel.Pwd != Convert.ToString(mySqlReader["UserPassword"]))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Query does not match");
        }
        else
        {
            passwordFounded = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Closes the Reader and empties the Command object.
    mySqlReader.Close();

    if (passwordFounded)
    {
        try
        {
            // Updates the UserPassword in the Db.
            mySqlCommand = mySqlConnect.CreateCommand();
            mySqlCommand.CommandText = Database_MySQLDef.UPDATEUSERS + "UserPassword = '" + UModel.ConfirmPwd + "' WHERE UserName = '" + UModel.Name + "';";
            mySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (MySqlException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was bordering on re-writing it, but this really helped me figure out what was going on. Thanks for the assist!